# How to move website from https domain to https domain (301)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, http-status-code-301

I want to move one of my websites to a new domain. All pages and URL structures will stay the same. I have a ssl lets encrypt cert installed for both domains.

Anyone can tell me the code to redirect `http` and `https` with wildcard to the new domain? (new domain is https://www.)

Comment: This question is off-topic in SO. Please read the help.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs this too i figured it out myself how to do it with nginx config:

```
    server {
server_name domain.com www.domain.com; 
rewrite ^ $scheme://www.new-domain.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```